# How to use the sound "ei" or "ey" in English conversation, which is quite popular in Australia?

Tags: word-usage, conversation

I lived in Australia for 13 years and many times when speaking to local Aussie people, I often hear they use "*ei*" or "*ey*" (I do not know how to write that word, and that is why I am asking you) like "*It's cool ey*" "*She is beautiful ey*".

See this conversation:

**Tom**: *My boss always criticizes me, blame me for no good reason, bla, bla, etc*

**Jack**: *He is bad ey*

There are not many Australian women saying "*ey*" like that. But it seems that more men especially young Aussie people saying "*ey*" like that.

I am not sure if it is popular in UK or in USA, but is quite popular in Australia.

How to use the sound "ei" or "ey" in English conversation, which is quite popular in Australia?

Can you give me a video link demonstrating how to use it?

Comment: Is that like the [Canadian eh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eh)?

Comment: I'm not recognising this, and I live in Melbourne. Perhaps a few more examples from your experience would help?

Comment: So , you mean Eh is a form of question tag?

Comment: @Kevin I wish people would stop saying that *eh* is Canadian. I'm from Wisconsin and it's perfectly normal there, doncha know.

Comment: I think Kevin should say "That is like the Canadian, Ey?" or "That is like the Canadian, isn't it?"

Comment: @tchrist I'm from Wisconsin too, and I don't hear it often back home. I've heard it from a number of Minnesotans though.

Comment: @Kevin My relatives from the north use it, and those from Minnesota. Those from the south don’t so much.

Comment: A video example is in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jmbv8kevQ-E at approximately 7:14. "What's her name, eh?"

Comment: @JEL, that is "what' her name, mate", not "what' her name, eh".  "Mate" is very popular in Australia

Comment: No, I think you're hearing the em in "name" as the first part of "mate", but the tee is just not there...the speaker does slur "name eh?", presumably in the rush of getting the necessary done. The phrase used is moot (for us) I suppose, and I don't know how to get an answer from the speaker/director/script writer. Do you mind telling me *why* you want a video example?

Comment: I am an English teaching assistant. I need to provide an example for my students to know how people use "Eh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just 'eh?', meaning "isn't it?'

[Macquarie Dictionary](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/resources/aus/word/map/search/word/eh/The%20Centre/) has an entry on it.

It's most common in Queensland, particularly Northern Queensland, but gets used elsewhere in Australia. It also gets used a bit by New Zealanders, a few of which have come to Australian shores.

Comment: can you give me a video link demonstrate that?

Comment: So "Eh" is only used as "isn't it" or can it be used for all question tags like "aren't they" or "aren't you"? Can I say "you are beautiful, Eh"? "They are bad, Eh"?

Comment: Another word used like this is: right? Which is short for: am i right?  It is meant to soften a declaritive statement by inviting you to agree.  Used habitually it just adds noise, or a bit of flavor, depending on how you feel.

Answer (score 1):

The Australian loconic drawl, a strict economy of words and enunciation, at work. In fact the original example, "It's cool,eh" would more likely be spoken, "Cool, eh".  The trailing 'eh' is almost always interrogative in Australian usage, but it is usually pitched as an invitation to acknowledge or agree with the statement, rather than as an enquiry.  So the sense of "Cool, eh" is "It's cool, is it not?", rather than "Is it cool?".  The usual response would be a slow nod, a "Yerrh".

The "eh" is the original English 'hey' from the Middle English "hei" in the interrogative sense. The OED's first written reference is dated c. 1225.